# MySQL Query not printing out data

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to retrieve some data from my table only for some reason I cant get it to return anything.

```
<?php

$curr_uemail = mysql_query("select * from produgg_users where produgg_users.id = ".$usersClass->userID().") or die(mysql_error())");    

$arr_uemail = mysql_fetch_array($data);

while($arr_uemail = mysql_fetch_array($data)) 
{
echo $arr_uemail['email'];
}

/*For Debugging purposes
echo $usersClass->userID();*/

?>
```

Can anybody see anything wrong with my syntax?

Comment: what is this? `") or die(whoops)");` didn't you notice the strange highlighting? x)

Comment: haha sorry I didnt, either way with that fixed it's still not working

Comment: so update your code. the other code should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of errors.

The first is

```
$curr_uemail = mysql_query("select * from produgg_users where produgg_users.id = ".$usersClass->userID()) or die(whoops);
```

**The second you shouldn't call** `mysql_fetch_assoc` before while, because if the result contains only 1 Record it would never enter in the while

The final code is:

```
$curr_uemail = mysql_query("select * from produgg_users where produgg_users.id = ".$usersClass->userID()) or die('whoops');

while($arr_uemail = mysql_fetch_array($curr_uemail)) {
echo $arr_uemail['email'];
}
```

As stated by **marc** if you have only one records than this could become:

```
$curr_uemail = mysql_query("select * from [etc]") or die('whoops');    
$arr_uemail = mysql_fetch_array($curr_uemail);
echo $arr_uemail['email'];
```

Comment: Sorry I've amended my original question.

Comment: that's because you should do `mysql_fetch_array($curr_uemail)` and not `$data` And I have edited my answer

Comment: Assuming that produgg_users.id is a PK field, the query could only ever produce once record at most, so the while loop is useless. a single fetch call would take care of things.

Answer (score 0):

I told you the first error via my comment.
But please enable error handling and do what the interpreter will tell you.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

What also can be erroneous, is this statement here:

```
while($arr_uemail = mysql_fetch_array($data))
```

You should enclose it with parentheses or the interpreter may warn you.

```
while(($arr_uemail = mysql_fetch_array($data)))
```

Comment: The extra brackets are useless. Omitting them does not cause a warning/error.

Comment: No, it may cause a warning, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/718415/warning-assignment-in-condition